# Pickle - Trying to read from a text file - UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 37: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, pickle

```
with open ("Save.txt" , "r+") as f:
        f.seek(0)
        if not f.read():
            print("No Data")
            while True:
                starter = int(input('Please pick a starter pokemon (1: Bulbasaur, 2: Charmander, 3: Squirtle) : '))
                if starter == 1 or starter == 2 or starter == 3:
                    break
                else:
                    print('That isnt an option!')
                continue

            if starter == 1:
                starterpokemon = encounter(databank[1].species , databank[1].number , 5 , 'Move1' , 'Move2' , 'Move3' , 'Move4' , 'Ability')
            elif starter == 2:
                starterpokemon = encounter(databank[4].species , databank[4].number , 5 , 'Move1' , 'Move2' , 'Move3' , 'Move4' , 'Ability')
            elif starter == 3:
                starterpokemon = encounter(databank[7].species , databank[7].number , 5 , 'Move1' , 'Move2' , 'Move3' , 'Move4' , 'Ability')

            fileObj = open('Save.txt','ab')
            pickle.dump(starterpokemon , fileObj)
            fileObj.close()

            fileObj = open('Save.txt','rb')
            object_file = pickle.load(fileObj)
            fileObj.close()
            print(object_file)

        else:
            print("Data Found")

items = loadall('Save.txt')

data = []
with open("Save.txt", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        try:
            data.append(pickle.load(f))
        except EOFError:
            break

for i in range(len(data)):
    print(data[i].name , data[i].number , data[i].level)

encountered = encounter(databank[1].species , databank[1].number , 5 , 'Move1' , 'Move2' , 'Move3' , 'Move4' , 'Ability')
print(encountered)

input()
fileObj = open('Save.txt','ab')
pickle.dump(encountered , fileObj)
fileObj.close()

fileObj = open('Save.txt','rb')
object_file = pickle.load(fileObj)
fileObj.close()
print(object_file)
```

Basically im trying to save the data about a pokemon to a text file using pickle, and it saves the data the first time you run it however trying to read the data it gives this error message:

**if not f.read():
File "C:\Users\Coloureaper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 37: character maps to**

if any of you know whats going on or how to fix it please let me know.